# Parameters and Join in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, parameters, pagination

I want to get all the data from two tables with join and paging the query so that there will be 10 rows present at all times. My first problem is that it works only when my page number is 1, without the join. My second problem (that will probably be resolved if I resolve the first problem) is that it doesn't even work if the page number is 1, if there is a join. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT INNER_TABLE.*, ROWNUM r
    FROM (
         SELECT details.*, extras.* FROM d_table details, e_table extras
         WHERE SYSDATE - details.UPDATE_DATE < 60
         ORDER BY details.UPDATE_DATE DESC
    ) INNER_TABLE
    WHERE ROWNUM < (:pageNum * :PerPage + 1)
)
WHERE r >= (((:pageNum - 1) * :perPage) +1);
```

It works without the join only on page 1. I do not understand why it works this way.
If someone can share light on my problem or to why am I stupid, please answer.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Any page number besides one returns an empty result. One returns what it should. 
EDITEDIT: The above is only true when the query is executed without the join. With the join, I get an error: "column ambiguously defined".

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work if there is a join". You get an error ? Empty result ?

Comment: Sorry. Edited..

Comment: Are you sure you posted the actual query you use ? `ORDER BY details.UPDATE_DATE < 60` is not a legal syntax in Oracle...

Comment: Sorry. Again. Editted the query and some more details.

Comment: Can you post the "without join" version of your query? The one that works with page 1 only.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my query is that it couldn't get the "details.*, extras.*" using "INNER_TABLE.*". My guess is that it couldn't recognize what the * in INNER_TABLE means. So the solution is using all the field names instead of the '*' anywhere in the query.